# Running a Pod from another Pod in the same kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am building an application which should execute tasks in a separate container/pods.
this application would be running in a specific namespace the new pods must be created in the same namespace as well.

I understand we can similar via custom CRD and Operators, but I found it is overly complicated and we need Golang knowledge for the same.

Is there any way this could be achived without having to learn Operators and GoLang?

I am ok to use `kubctl` or `api` within my container and wanted to connect the host and to the same namespace.

Comment: I'd generally set this up using a job queue like RabbitMQ, and have a long-running worker (or multiple) with a separate Deployment.  This avoids needing to do anything Kubernetes-specific, and lets you limit how much work gets done in parallel if a huge number of requests show up at the same time.

Comment: can you elaborate on the use of  RabbitMQ in this scenario David Maze
 . why will you use RabbitMQ? in order to control the stack of pod creation?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is certainly possible using a `ServiceAccount` and then connecting to the API from within the Pod.

- First, create a `ServiceAccount` in your namespace using

  ```
  kubectl create serviceaccount my-service-account
  ```
- For your newly created `ServiceAccount`, give it the permissions you want using [`Roles` and `RoleBindings`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). The subject would be something like this:

  ```
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: my-service-account
    namespace: my-namespace
  ```
- Then, add the `ServiceAccount` to the Pod from where you want to create other Pods from (see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)). Credentials are automatically mounted inside the Pod using `automountServiceAccountToken`.
- Now from inside the Pod you can either use `kubectl` or call the API using the credentials inside the Pod. There are libraries for a lot of programming languages to talk to Kubernetes, use those.